# Selecting first tab by default when page is loaded in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs, nav

I have the following angular code for showing student info in the tabbed format.
Following is the student.html class

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="studentTab in studentList"
            ng-class="{active: selectedStudentTab.name === studentTab.name}">
            <a ng-click="selectStudentTab(studentTab)">{{studentTab.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" ng-repeat="studentTab in studentList"
                ng-show="selectedStudentTab.name === studentTab.name">
                <div style="padding: 35px; text-align: left;">
                    <div ng-repeat="project in studentTab.projects">
                    <p><pre>{{project.log}}</pre></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my studentController.js I have assigned the oth element of studentList to the tab, following is the code:

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $rootScope.initOrRedirectToLandingPage($scope.loadStudents);
};

$scope.studentList = [];

$rootScope.loadStudents = function(){...
};

$scope.selectedStudentTab = $scope.studentList[0];

$scope.selectStudentTab = function (studentTab) {
        $scope.selectedStudentTab = studentTab;
};
```

Here the tabs are created properly, but the first tab is not selected/active by default on loading of the page and becomes active only on the click event.
Can someone help me to figure out what am I missing? any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `selectedStudentTab`? How does your JavaScript look?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller after you load the `studentList` assign the `selectedStudentTab` to the first item in the list.

```
$scope.studentList = [...];
$scope.selectedStudentTab = $scope.studentList[0];
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I have done the same in my controller. still I see that first tab is not selected by default.

Comment: What is the contents of your loadStudents function?  Does it contain a promise?

Comment: basically you need to make sure that you are setting the selected value after the values have been loaded into the list. Looking at your code, you basically set the list to an empty array and then select the first item from it, but never loaded the data into the array first.  You defined your function to load the list, however it wasn’t called prior to selecting the first item.